# If a normed space $X$ is reflexive, then $Q(B_X)=B_{X^{**}}$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a reflexive normed space, let $Q$ be the natural map from $X$ to $X^{**}$, and let $B_X,B_{X^{**}}$ denote the closed unit ball of $X$ and $X^{**}$. Then how to get $Q(B_X)=B_{X^{**}}$?

Comment: By hypothesis $Q$ is an isomorphism (in particular bijective). Since it is isometric, given $y \in B_{X^{**}}$ the $x$ which is going to $y$ must be in the closed unit ball himself.

Comment: It follows from the Hahn-Banch theorem that $||Qx||_{X^{**}}=||x||_X$.